# Sort by 2 columns with hierarchical sorting [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe such as:

```
COL1 COL2
1 pupa male
2 pupa female
3 pupae female
4 larva female
5 larvae female & male
6 pupe female
10 adult female 
12 NA female
7 pupa male
8 pupae male
9 adult male
11 pupae NA
13 NA male
```

so the idea is to first sort by `COL2` where I should sort any value containing `female` in first:

```
str.contains("female") > !str.contains("female")
```

`COL2 > COL1` so

Then sort by `COL1` where I should first put value containing `pup` then `larv` then `others`

```
str.contains('pup') > str.contains("larv") > other
```

Here is the expected value:

```
COL1 COL2
2 pupa female
3 pupae female
6 pupe female
4 larva female
5 larvae female & male
10 adult female 
12 NA female
1 pupa male
7 pupa male
8 pupae male
9 adult male
11 pupae NA
13 NA male
```

So far I only succeed to sort by COL1 using:

```
df['Sex'] = pd.Categorical(df['Sex'], ['female','pooled male and female', 'male and female','male'])

df=new_df.sort_values("Sex")
```

But as you can see here the solution needs a list instead of a `.str.contains` solution (which is more globally)

Comment: If you are first sorting by `Col2`, shouldn't the row `12` in your expected output will come before `male` values?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma you are right, I modified thanks

Comment: Also I think `pupae Na` should be before `adult male`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best things i found for you is to convert these labels to numbers & then sort.

Ex. `female & starts with female = 1`,`male = 0` & `others = -1`, Same way for col1.

Then it will be easy to sort. Below i have something for you -

```
data = [['pupa', 'male'],
['pupa', 'female'],
['pupae', 'female'],
['larva', 'female'],
['larvae', 'female & male'],
['pupe', 'female'],
['pupa', 'male'],
['pupae', 'male'],
['adult', 'male'],
['adult', 'female'], 
['pupae', 'NA'],
['NA', 'female'],
['NA', 'male']] 

import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2'])
data_df
    col1    col2
0   pupa    male
1   pupa    female
2   pupae   female
3   larva   female
4   larvae  female & male
5   pupe    female
6   pupa    male
7   pupae   male
8   adult   male
9   adult   female
10  pupae   NA
11  NA      female
12  NA      male

data_df['col2_cond'] = data_df['col2'].apply(
    lambda x:1 if x.startswith('female') else (-1 if x == 'NA' else 0)
)
data_df['col1_cond'] = data_df['col1'].apply(
    lambda x:2 if x.find('pup') != -1 else (1 if x.find('larv') != -1 else (-1 if x == 'NA' else 0))
)

data_df.sort_values(['col2_cond', 'col1_cond'], ascending=[False, False])
    col1    col2      col2_cond col1_cond
1   pupa    female          1   2
2   pupae   female          1   2
5   pupe    female          1   2
3   larva   female          1   1
4   larvae  female & male   1   1
9   adult   female          1   0
11  NA      female          1   -1
0   pupa    male            0   2
6   pupa    male            0   2
7   pupae   male            0   2
8   adult   male            0   0
12  NA      male            0   -1
10  pupae   NA             -1   2
```

**Note** - I considered `NA` as string elements. But you can check for `None` types.